# Complex multi-filter routes in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

My app has (somewhat complex) filtering requirements, in that a user is able to filter on two types of categories, each of which must allow sub-categories. Oh yeah, I must allow multiple categories and sub-categories, and I want each combination to have a shareable, and (somewhat) readable URL.

To put it concretely, here is the generalized scheme I've come up with illustrated by an example:

```
/ontario[toronto,waterloo],quebec/accommodations[hotels],attractions
```

This would show Hotels (sub-category of Accommodations) and all Attractions in the cities of Toronto and Waterloo in Ontario province, and in any city in Quebec province.

So basically:

```
"/{comma-seperated regions with comma-seperated towns in square braces}/{comma-seperated categories with comma-seperated subcategories in square braces}"
```

I'm pretty sure this won't work by default, and being somewhat new to Ember, I'm wondering where to start with this scheme. Probably I'll have to override the routes (and perhaps link-to?) somewhere.

Any general tips would be appreciated!

If you think this is a terrible idea, I welcome that feedback too. The alternative is an even uglier query-param method, so I kind of like this right now.

Comment: Hey have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164461/how-do-you-maintain-the-page-state-so-that-you-can-provide-permalinks-using-emb/18249404#18249404 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165072/is-resource-nesting-the-only-way-to-enable-multiple-dynamic-segments/15174766#15174766 . I guess this is a rough direction what you are looking for. You are right, that this is not totally easy with Ember out of the box and it requires some changes to approaching a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a like filter with ember.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554335/how-to-do-a-like-filter-with-ember-js)

Comment: No, it's not related at all. This is a question about routing.

Comment: @elsurudo The word `route` is not mentioned in the question. `filter` is part of the title, and mentioned twice otherwise. `string-mangling` is part of the solution, which could be simplified using the `map` and `filter` in the related question.

Comment: I think that's a bit of a stretch. The title of the question is "Complex multi-filter routes in Ember". Routes is in the title!

Comment: Have you thought about using Embers query params for this?

Comment: Yeah, but the aim was to have "pretty" URLs, not just a bunch of query params tacked onto one another :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time understanding the Ember Router, this ended up being pretty straight-forward.

In the route's "model" method, I simply use the params hash to deduce the proper model to use. This isn't so straightforward in my case because of the complex dynamic portions of my URL, but this was mainly just string-mangling code.

The other side of it is overriding the "serialize" method on the route. This does the opposite of the "model" method, and returns a hash of the dynamic "params" for a particular model object. This is used to serialize a model into the URL.

With these two methods implemented properly, it works beautifully.